# FastApi keep a game state for every instance

Tags: python, fastapi

I am currently working on a small board game while trying to get accustomed to FastApi, and what I do is keep the game's state in some variables in the `app` object

```
app.players = {
    0: Player(),
    1: Player()
}
app.game = Game(app.players)
app.turn = 0
app.winner = NO_WINNER
```

When the player selects a square it's actually a Jinja template generated link like `/select/player=0/square={{ players[0].points }}` so it refreshes the page but gets back the state from the globals. It lands back into a route like this:

```
@app.get("/select/")
def square_selected(request: Request, player: int = Query(ge=0, le=1), square: int = Query(ge=0, le=5)):
    app.winner, app.turn = app.game.calculate_move(player, square, app.turn)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {
        "request": request,
        "players": app.players,
        "turn": app.turn % 2,
        "winner": app.winner
    })
```

The problem with this of course is that it's the same instance of the game for everyone that opens a browser window to it. I would like to have a new instance for every window open, and I guess it has to be done using a db or redis cache or something, and assign a unique id for every session, but I have some questions.

1. is there a fastapi way of doing this? I am imagining it's a common
   issue, but couldn't find an exact response on google.
2. How do we generate the unique id? In javascript inside the template? I think it will be
   regenerated every time the player clicks something because of the
   refresh.
3. How to know when to clean up old sessions from the db? One
   way I saw was with websockets, but again, they are closed and
   recreated everytime I click a box.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this of course is that it's the same instance of the game for everyone that opens a browser window to it. **I would like to have a new instance for every window open**, and I guess it has to be done using a db or redis cache or something, and assign a unique id for every session, but I have some questions.

1. See how [fastapi](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) websocket works if you want to have a new instance for each window open. You may also need some global space, perhaps variable or redis, to store all the sessions and communicate between them.
2. Once a websocket connection has been established, a transport built on top of TCP sockets ensures that only one user will be using it. Moreover, if your website lacks authorization, the front-end server may transmit an identifier as the first message.
3. Websockets are necessary if you're developing a real-time game because you probably won't need to reload your website with every user click.

Nevertheless, this is how you can accomplish it if you truly don't want to use websockets.

- There should be an entry point for the game, such as "/game/start."
- Client enters his username into a POST request and sends it to "/game/start," and as a result, the server generates a random identifier for that user, such as "SECRET KEY."
- Client should store that "SECRET KEY" in "localStorage" or "sessionStorage" in the browser and send that SECRET KEY to the server with every request, as a header or in the body, or possibly in the cookie, to identify himself.
- You should also keep that "SECRET KEY" in order to authorize each client, and when the game is over, you can easily remove players' "SECRET KEY."